# Stop setInterval Until Event Reoccurs

Tags: javascript

I've made some share options where the user clicks on a social share button on the first card, a window opens, and when they close the window it initiates the change to the next card.

Here is how I open and track the close of the window:

### Javascript

```
var shareWindow;

//Open the window on call
function openShareWin(link) {
  shareWindow = window.open(link, 'rmShare', 'location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=520,height=350');
}

//Initiate card flip on close
var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (shareWindow.closed !== false) { // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
        flipOnClose();
    }
}, 200);

function flipOnClose() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.share-rotate').trigger('click');
  });
}
```

Everything works just fine... the first time. But if the user returns to the share menu (without refresh), opens the window, shares the site, and closes the window, the event does not fire.

I am aware that this is because I call `clearInterval`, but I must do this in order to keep `setInterval` from flipping through the rest of the cards automatically.

How do I cause `flipOnClose()` to fire once when the user closes the window, and also fire when the action is performed each successive time?

EDIT: I'm also getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've got you problem, but as I see, you could solve it by putting the interval creation inside the same function that opens the windows. Then, everytime the window is opened, the interval is created. Like this:

```
var shareWindow;

//Open the window on call
function openShareWin(link) {
    shareWindow = window.open(link, 'rmShare', 'location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=520,height=350');

    //Initiate card flip on close
    var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (shareWindow.closed !== false) { // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
            flipOnClose();
        }
    }, 200);
}

function flipOnClose() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.share-rotate').trigger('click');
    });
}
```

If I'm wrong, please tell me.

Comment: It worked! I was wondering if I needed to wrap the timer somehow, and this is so much tidier. Thank you so much!